# When deploying django app, manage.py cant find views.py

Tags: python, django, deployment

I am trying to deploy a simple Django app that makes a user login and then serves a "hello world" on success. I use white noise for static.

The web service builds correctly, but when deploying, I am getting the error `module views.py can not be found`. I can not understand why though as all paths seem to be correct. I use two different settings files; one for local development utilizing pip, and one for production using Gunicorn and a build.sh script (as per Render.com documentation).

These are my server logs for deployment:

```
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM  Traceback (most recent call last):
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM      main()
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "manage.py", line 19, in main
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM      execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM      utility.execute()
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM      self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM      self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM      output = self.handle(*args, **options)
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM      res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 75, in handle
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM      self.check(databases=[database])
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 423, in check
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM      databases=databases,
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM      new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM      return check_resolver(resolver)
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM      return check_method()
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 412, in check
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM      for pattern in self.url_patterns:
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM      res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM      patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM      res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM      return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/user_authentication/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM      from .views import login_view
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'user_authentication.views'
Nov 8 11:05:22 PM  ==Build failed
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from .views import login_view
from .views import hello_world_view
from .views import home_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', login_view, name='login'),
    path('hello_world/', hello_world_view, name='hello_world'),
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home_view(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def login_view(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('hello_world')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'login.html', context)

def hello_world_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("Succes!!")

@login_required
def hello_world(request):
    return render(request, 'hello_world.html')
```

It looks to me that my `manage.py` file is failing, and so `views.py` is not found and the deployment fails. I think it is deployment, server, or settings related, as it works fine locally. Things I checked:

- `views.py` is in the correct directory
- User authentication is listed under `INSTALLED_APPS`
- The directory contains `__init__.py`
- Correct settings module is loaded
- `ROOT_URLCONF` is correct
- `WSGI_APPLICATION` is correct

Any ideas on what could be making the `manage.py` not find `views.py` would be great. I'm happy to provide further information if that would be of help.

Kind regards.